# Anchor in table

Tags: html, html-table, anchor

I have a long table, and I want the client to scroll to a given row when the page is loaded. I made a jsFiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/s28hf39e/2/

```css
td {
  height: 200px
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<a href="#row-1">Link to row 1</a>
<a href="#row-2">Link to row 2</a>
<a href="#row-3">Link to row 3</a>
<a href="#row-4">Link to row 4</a>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a id="row-1"></a>Row 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a id="row-2"></a>Row 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a id="row-3"></a>Row 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a id="row-4"></a>Row 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The links works properly, but the page do not scroll to the expected row when calling http://my.url/#row-4

What am I missing to scroll to the expected row on page loading ?

Answer (score 0):

You havs use something like that:

```
<a href="#row-1">Link to row 1</a>
<a href="#row-2">Link to row 2</a>
<a href="#row-3">Link to row 3</a>
<a href="#row-4">Link to row 4</a>
<table>
 <tr id="row-1"><td>Row 1</td></tr>
 <tr id="row-2"><td>Row 2</td></tr>
 <tr id="row-3"><td>Row 3</td></tr>
 <tr id="row-4"><td>Row 4</td></tr>  
</table>
```